# problems with angular 6 login view component

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to write a registration form using Angular 6 with Django backend and I'm facing these problems:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>
> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
>   (" < h2>Login
>
> ][formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
>
> ```
>   <label for="use"): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@1:6
> ```
>
> at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)

my code is here:

login.component.ts:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private Auth: AuthService,
              private alertService: AlertService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    // reset login status
    this.Auth.logout();

    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() {
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.Auth.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }
}
```

login.component.html:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <img *ngIf="loading" src="Img_Link_Here" />
        <a [routerLink]="['/create_user']" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm angular beginner, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common error, to fix this, you just need to import ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms in your module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! 
I'm also interested now, is it worthy grouping data (`username`+`password` as dict using `formbuilder` in `ngOnUnit`) and sending to backend as it is then, or its better to keep each value apart and send as headers?
If second option is better, may be you could give me extra advice on rewriting it?
Im just unsure about memory management and etc

Comment: Use the second option , since it's not a complex data. Mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 1):

you have to import FormModule in a module.ts file like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
],
declrations: [
AppComponent
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```